# What are the 16 critical infrastructure sectors the US demands a stop to Russian cyber attacks on?

Tags: united-states, infrastructure, cyber-warfare

At their Geneva summit meeting, U.S. President Joe Biden handed Putin a list of 16 critical infrastructure sectors that must be "off limits" from cyber attacks.

> "I talked about the proposition that certain critical infrastructure should be off-limits to attack, period, by cyber or any other means," the president stated. "I gave them a list, and I don't have it in front of me, if I am not mistaken, of 16 entities — 16 defined as critical infrastructure, from the energy sector to our water systems." — [Yahoo News](https://news.yahoo.com/biden-gave-putin-list-16-175500657.html)

> Biden-Putin summit: US demands a stop to Russian cyber attacks on critical infrastructure — [The Telegraph](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/2021/06/16/biden-putin-summit-us-russia-leaders-meeting-talks-geneva/)

> Biden Vows Retaliation On Any Future Russian Hacks On Critical Infrastructure — [Forbes](https://www.forbes.com/sites/joewalsh/2021/06/16/biden-vows-retaliation-on-any-future-russian-cyberattacks-on-critical-infrastructure/)

**Is it known what sectors (or specific entities) are in this list?**

I found [Homeland Security Presidential Directive 7: Critical Infrastructure Identification, Prioritization, and Protection](https://www.cisa.gov/homeland-security-presidential-directive-7), but it looks rather dated (December 2003), contains a fewer number of entities, and mostly covers a "regular" terrorism like bombing etc while touching cyberspace rather tangentially.

Looking for a better source.

Comment: Kinda blows my mind that the demand isn't "Stop all cyber attacks".

Comment: @Ryan_L That kind of agreements are always reciprocal, so I guess the demand wasn't "stop all cyber-attacks" because the USA didn't want its hands tied there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [US Cybersecurity & Infrastructure Security Agency](https://www.cisa.gov/critical-infrastructure-sectors):

> There are 16 critical infrastructure sectors whose assets, systems, and networks, whether physical or virtual, are considered so vital to the United States that their incapacitation or destruction would have a debilitating effect on security, national economic security, national public health or safety, or any combination thereof. Presidential Policy Directive 21 (PPD-21): Critical Infrastructure Security and Resilience advances a national policy to strengthen and maintain secure, functioning, and resilient critical infrastructure. This directive supersedes Homeland Security Presidential Directive 7.

On that page, they are listed as:

- Chemical Sector
- Commercial Facilities Sector
- Communications Sector
- Critical Manufacturing Sector
- Dams Sector
- Defense Industrial Base Sector
- Emergency Services Sector
- Energy Sector
- Financial Services Sector
- Food and Agriculture Sector
- Government Facilities Sector
- Healthcare and Public Health Sector
- Information Technology Sector
- Nuclear Reactors, Materials, and Waste Sector
- Transportation Sector
- Water and Wastewater Systems Sector

This [WP article](https://www.washingtonpost.com/politics/2021/06/17/cybersecurity-202-here-are-four-cyber-takeaways-biden-putin-summit/) agrees it is this list. This [IT Security Guru article](https://www.itsecurityguru.org/2021/06/17/biden-says-16-sectors-should-be-off-limits-to-attack/?utm_source=rss&utm_medium=rss&utm_campaign=biden-says-16-sectors-should-be-off-limits-to-attack) says we don't know for sure it's this list, but says it most likely is. This [Verdict.co.uk article](https://www.verdict.co.uk/critical-infrastructure-targets-biden-putin/) states:

> Tom Kellermann, a member of the US Secret Service’s Cybersecurity Investigations Board, told ZDNet that Biden was referring to 16 critical infrastructure sectors as defined by the Cybersecurity and Infrastructure Security Agency (CISA).

[Politico.com says](https://www.politico.com/news/2021/06/16/biden-putin-russia-cyberattacks-494888) "seemingly a reference to the list composed by the Homeland Security Department’s cyber wing."

Most of the articles I read discussing the meeting between Putin and Biden were unsure of the list, but as I showed, ZDNet at least quoted a government official by name that the CISA list is the one.

Comment: Interesting that Population (people) and Academic are not included....